# Buy X Get X for free formula in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shopping-cart, price, promotions

In a buy one get one free situation, it is simple to calculate, just had to divided by 2 to the quantity we want(ex: buy 3 get 3 for free, so we get 6).

But when it gets more complex, like buy 4 get 1 for free, what would be the best purchasing option if we want to buy say 13(the answer is to buy 11 because you get 2 for free)? I found it interesting is that it is easy to calculate, but to put it in code, I am lost.

In buy 4 get 1 free, this is the pattern I found, but again, I have no clue how to actually put it in code.

Basically, I want to formulate the "buy X get X free", so when a given situation, it will output the best purchase option. Example, if I want to buy 13 of them, it will output "11".

```
the quantity we need:    we only need to buy:    what we end up having:

          1                        1                       1
          2                        2                       2
          3                        3                       3
          4                        4                       5
          5                        4                       5
          6                        5                       6
          7                        6                       7
          8                        7                       8
          9                        8                       10
         10                        8                       10
         11                        9                       11
         12                       10                       12
         13                       11                       13
         14                       12                       15
         15                       12                       15
          .                        .                        .
          .                        .                        .
          .                        .                        .
```

Comment: To put *what* in code, exactly? Do you want a function for the optimal buying strategy depending on minimum items needed and discount plan?

Comment: This isn't a `python` problem (as of yet and given the current question's form), or anything to do with programming for that matter. You should solve the arithmetic and show us where you got stuck _coding_ those calculations.

Comment: I am sorry for not making it clear, I want to formulate the "buy X get X free", so when a given situation, it will output the best purchase option. Example, if I want to buy 13 of them, it will output "11". Hope that make sense

Comment: Please include that in the question, also include your attempt to code that. If you really lost on where to start, start from Python tutorials

Comment: Hi @timgeb, sorry not making it clear, yes, making an optimal buying strategy depending on minimum items and discount plan is what I try to do. Based on the answer below, I will try and improve my code, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward: you want to find how many full packs, and how many non-pack items you need to get. Integral division is handy.

```
def buy_to_acquire(desired, buy=1, free=0):
    pack = buy + free
    buy_packs = desired // pack
    buy_individual = desired % pack
    return buy * buy_packs + buy_individual

buy_to_acquire(13, buy=4, free=1)
# => 11
```

Alternate version is not as easy to understand, but it's a bit faster for the computer:

```
import math
def buy_to_acquire(desired, buy=1, free=0):
    return math.ceil(desired * buy / (buy + free))
```

Comment: Wow... why didn't I think of it... you made it so simple. Thanks

Comment: ```
import math
def buy_to_acquire(desired, buy=1, free=0):
    if desired > buy:   
      return math.ceil(desired * buy / (buy + free))
    else: 
       return desired;
```
Amadan's answer is correct but fails when `desired` is less than or equal to `buy`.